# Why i'm getting and error while sending email data to my database?

Tags: database, electron, syntax-error, node-sqlite3

So my probleme is that i'm getting this error: `Uncaught Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "@gmail": syntax error`
while i'm INSERTING or UPDATING in the database.

I'm working with sqlite3 and electron. Here is my code:

```
function addPatient(){
  var req = 'INSERT INTO patient(nom, prenom, age, tel, mail, sexe, paiement) VALUES('+li_nom.value+','+li_prenom.value+','+li_age.value+','+li_tel.value+','+li_mail.value+','+li_sexe.value+','+li_paiement.value+')';
  db.run(req);
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("done");
}
```

PS: i'm getting the data from form value.

If you need more information do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What is the runtime value of `req`?  Basically, the database is telling you that the SQL code had invalid syntax.  So your next step should be to examine that SQL code and see what it is.

Comment: The runtime value of `req` is the line above `db.run(req)`. I tried to know were the problem were this morning but i found nothing.

Comment: That's not the runtime value, that's the code which *generates* the runtime value.  Note for example that `"@gmail.com"` exists nowhere on that line.  Your first debugging step is to examine the SQL code that you're executing, not the code which *generates* the SQL code that you're executing.  You're attempting to fix a problem, the last thing you should be doing is assuming that line of code is working as expected without checking.

Comment: oh okay sorry let me check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your SQL query via string concatenation, which leaves it vulnerable to SQL injection and otherwise malformed queries.

Your query basically ends up looking like this when the database receives it:

`INSERT INTO patient(nom, prenom, age, tel, mail, sexe, paiement) VALUES(name,prename,25,555555555,example@gmail.com,male,500)`

The issues here:

1. String values need to be quoted in your query
2. The `@` symbol is used for variables (when not part of a true string, or not quoted)

You need to use parameterized queries. This will resolve both of these issues *and* protect you against pretty much any SQL injection. You create placeholders in the query, then set programmatically populate them via the library.

Comment: So if understand well, i've to do: ```INSERT INTO patient (nom, prenom, age, tel, mail, sexe, paiement) VALUES(${li_age.value},${li_age.tel},${li_age.mail},${li_age.sexe},${li_age.paiement}';```

Comment: That answer *does not* use a parameterized query.  It uses string interpolation, which is just as open to SQL injection as string concatenation is.  @DreadLine: The documentation for the node sqlite3 library includes examples of how to use parameters in a query: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/insert/

Comment: Okay guys its working thanks a lot for helping me !! :)

Comment: @DreadLine yes, parameterized queries work the same for insert, update and delete